# Chess - How to deduce the position of figures?

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, logic

It is necessary to write functions

- To draw a chessboard, function `drowChess (8,8)`
- For parting figures on it in random order.function addFigures(`['black']`=>`['King']`,`'white'`=>`['Rook','Officer']`).To begin with two opposing figures.
  For example the king of white and black Rook.so much so that every time you call this function, they do not contradict the laws of chess.
- Possible function must be universal, that is, if to set the third
  figure into function that it is not broke.

In short I think so - we must try to calculate the algorithm for their positions.I've already started to solve the problem but the algorithm is a little hard.

```
$x = 8;
$y = 8;

$xb = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'];

function drowChess($horisonal, $vertical, $xb)
{
    $style = "width:30px;height:30px;";
    $white = "background:white;color:black;text-align:center";
    $black = "background:black;color:white;text-align:center";
    $color = $black;
    echo "<table border='1' style='margin:0 auto' cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th style='width:30px;height:30px;'>$horisonal/$vertical</th>";
    foreach($xb as $word){
        echo "<th style='width:30px;height:30px;'>".$word."</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    for($y = 1; $y <= $vertical; $y++)
    {
        if($color == $black)
            $color = $white;
        else
            $color = $black;
        echo "<tr>";
        for($x = 1; $x <= $horisonal; $x++)
        {
            if($color == $black)
                $color = $white;
            else
                $color = $black;
            if($x == 1)
            {
                    echo "<th style='$style'>".$y ."</th>";
            }
            echo "<td style='$style $color'>".$xb[$x-1] .$y."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

drowChess($x, $y,$xb);
```

I start so

```
$figures = [
    'King' => function($x,$y)
    {
        //Logic + algorithm...
        return [[$x,$y],[$x,$y],[$x,$y]];//Relevant possible positions , given a predetermined position
    },
    'Rook' => function($x,$y)
    {
        //Logic + algorithm ...
        return [[$x,$y],[$x,$y],[$x,$y]];//given a predetermined position 
    },
    //And so on for all figures
];
```

After

```
function addFigures(array $figures,array $algoritm)
{
     foreach($figures as $figure)
     {
          if(!isset($algoritm[$figure])) return ['success'=>false,'message'=>'Such a figure does not exist'];
          return $algoritm[$figure];
     }
}

addFigures(['King','Rook']);
```

For example:

If King on position (B2), Rook It can not be in the positions  (A1,B1,C1,C2,C3,B3,A3,A2 and A8,H2 ...), need an algorithm,and proper alignment of tactics

**Need to write the function**

```
function getFigurePositions($x,y)
{
   //logic for figure -  King
    return ['A1','A2','A3','B3','C3','C2','C1','B1'];//available positions(I mean x,y coordinates )
}
getFigurePositions(['figure'=>'king','positions'=>'2,2']);
getFigurePositions(['figure'=>'Rock','positions'=>'3,7']);
```

You can write only the  algorithm and the tactics of the following steps.
What do you think how to implement it,is there a better approach? Thanks.

Comment: _"To draw a chessboard"_  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086090/trying-to-make-a-reusable-function-to-make-cells-in-a-row-chess-board/

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. Do you want to know how to return a random position on the chess board that is valid? But doing so without having to do several moves from the starting position?

Comment: In the question I drawed the board.I need an algorithm figures

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek for example if King on position (B2), Rook It can not be in the positions  (A1,B1,C1,C2,C3,B3,A3,A2 and A8,H2 ...), need an algorithm,and proper alignment of tactics

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan I'm going to assume you mean moves that are not check? That being said what you mentioned doesn't make sense. Why would the Rook not be able to be on A1,C1,C3,A3, and A8? Even so being in check isn't against any rules if the Rook is the one moving, the only real invalid position for the Rook is B2.

Comment: Imagine that King is black  but Rock is white.If the Rock will be in these positions, the king will eat it

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek it is also, in principle doesn't matter.It is necessary to return the coordinates available for figure

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan The king being able to that the Rook doesn't mean the position is invalid (it also cannot take it on A8). There are several cases when more pieces are on the board it can be used as a tactic for checkmate. This question is unclear, but it seems you are wanting a chess AI that will determine if a move is *"not bad"*. That is a very general task, and way to broad as a question itself.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek I'm telling you it is necessary to write some sort of algorithm which returns available to the steps of the King or Rook.I'm thinking of this algorithm.If you can help thanks

Comment: For example function getFigurePositions(['figure'=>'king','positions'=>'2,2'])//2,2 = B2
{
    return ['A1','A2','A3','B3','C3','C2','C1','B1'];
}

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek See my answer,I have written the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I derive an algorithm for the king and for the rook.For other figures move the same scheme.

```
drowChess($x, $y,$xb);
$figures = [
    'King' => function ($x,$y)
    {
        if((!$x or $x < 0) or (!$y or $y < 0))
            return "Poziciya $x $y naxoditsya za polem";
        $xb = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'];
        $currentPosition = $xb[$x-1].$y;

        $x1 = $x-1;
        $y1 = $y;

        $x2 = $x-1;
        $y2 = $y-1;

        $x3 = $x-1;
        $y3 = $y+1;

        $x4 = $x+1;
        $y4 = $y;

        $x5 = $x+1; 
        $y5 = $y-1;

        $x6 = $x+1; 
        $y6 = $y+1;

        $x7 = $x;   
        $y7 = $y-1;

        $x8 = $x;   
        $y8 = $y+1;

        $positions = [];

        if(isset($xb[$x1-1]) && $y1 && $y1 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x1-1].$y1] = ['x'=>$x1,'y'=>$y1];
        if(isset($xb[$x2-1]) && $y2 && $y2 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x2-1].$y2] = ['x'=>$x2,'y'=>$y2];
        if(isset($xb[$x3-1]) && $y3 && $y3 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x3-1].$y3] = ['x'=>$x3,'y'=>$y3];
        if(isset($xb[$x4-1]) && $y4 && $y4 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x4-1].$y4] = ['x'=>$x4,'y'=>$y4];
        if(isset($xb[$x5-1]) && $y5 && $y5 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x5-1].$y5] = ['x'=>$x5,'y'=>$y5];
        if(isset($xb[$x6-1]) && $y6 && $y6 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x6-1].$y6] = ['x'=>$x6,'y'=>$y6];
        if(isset($xb[$x7-1]) && $y7 && $y7 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x7-1].$y7] = ['x'=>$x7,'y'=>$y7];
        if(isset($xb[$x8-1]) && $y8 && $y8 <= 8 )
            $positions[$xb[$x8-1].$y8] = ['x'=>$x8,'y'=>$y8];

        return [
            'Korol na' => $currentPosition,
            'Dostupnie emu xodi'=>$positions
        ];
    },
    'Rook' => function($x,$y)
    {
        if((!$x or $x < 0) or (!$y or $y < 0))
            return "Poziciya $x $y naxoditsya za polem";

        $positions = [];
        $xb = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'];
        $currentPosition = $xb[$x-1].$y;

        //V pravo vniz i vverx
        $yrb = $yrt = $y;
        for( $x1 = $x+1; $x1 <= 8 ; $x1++ )
        {
            //Diaganal to rigth bottom
            if((++$yrb) <= 8)
                $positions[$xb[$x1-1].($yrb)] = ['x' => $x1, 'y' => $yrb];

            //Diaganal to rigth top
            if((--$yrt) > 0)
                $positions[$xb[$x1-1].($yrt)] = ['x' => $x1, 'y' => $yrt];
        }

        //V pravo vniz i vverx
        $ylb = $ylt = $y;
        for( $x2 = $x-1; $x2 >= 1 ; $x2-- )
        {
            //Diaganal to left bottom
            if((++$ylb) <= 8){
                $positions[$xb[$x2-1].($ylb)] = ['x' => $x2, 'y' => $ylb];
            }

            //Diaganal to left top
            if((--$ylt) > 0){
                $positions[$xb[$x2-1].($ylt)] = ['x' => $x2, 'y' => $ylt];
            }
        }

        return [
            'Rook na' => $currentPosition,
            'Dostupnie emu xodi'=>$positions
        ];
    },
];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($figures['Rook'](5,5));
```

Well, if we have the available steps we can write a function that will call them with different settings until they are available steps are not different.